# Finding all adjacent elements in a 2D array

Tags: c

I am working on a project where at one point I am stuck.

My question is for example I have the following 2D array containing 3 different integers.

```
2 2 2 2 1 
1 2 2 2 1 
3 3 2 3 2 
3 1 3 3 1 
1 1 2 3 1 
1 3 1 3 3
```

What I want is to find the longest adjacent elements chain of array of any number contained in the array.

Like in the above array the longest chain is of digit 2.

```
2 2 2 2
  2 2 2
    2
```

Can anyone just guide me as to what I have to do to achieve this goal?

Comment: What have you tried, and how doesn't it work? Also, is the array bounded, toroidal, or spherical?

Comment: Are you writing a minesweeper? :)

Comment: Do you want the number of the longest chain of adjacent elements (e.g. 8, in your example)? Or do you want their positions in the 2D array?

Comment: @Goran I think it is probably something more like Bejeweled :)

Comment: Thanks Everybody.. Basically I am Writing the Code for the cpu Player of a puzzle game called bubble breaker and what i want is to delete step by step all the bubbles untill there is no adjacent bubbles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to draw than to explain...

```
2 2 2 2 1 => A A A A B => (A: 4, B: 1)
1 2 2 2 1 => C A A A B => (A: 3 + 4, B: 1 + 1, C: 1)
3 3 2 3 2 => D D A E F => (A: 1 + 7, B: 2, C: 1, D: 2, E: 1, F: 1)
3 1 3 3 1 => D G E E G => (A: 8, B: 2, C: 1, D: 2 + 1, E: 2 + 1, F: 1, G: 1)
1 1 2 3 1 => ...
1 3 1 3 3 => ...
```

**update**:

And now, with some real code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 5

unsigned char eles[ROWS][COLS] = { { 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 }, 
                                   { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 }, 
                                   { 3, 3, 2, 3, 2 }, 
                                   { 3, 1, 3, 3, 1 }, 
                                   { 1, 1, 2, 3, 1 }, 
                                   { 1, 3, 1, 3, 3 } };

struct zone {
  int acu;
  int row, col;
  int refs;
};

typedef struct zone zone;

zone *
new_zone(int row, int col) {
  zone *z = (zone *)malloc(sizeof(zone));
  z->col = col;
  z->row = row;
  z->refs = 1;
  z->acu = 0;
}

void croak (const char *str) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", str);
  exit(1);
}

void
free_zone(zone *z) {
  if (z->refs != 0) croak("free_zone: reference count is not cero");
  free(z);
}

zone *
ref_zone(zone *z) {
  z->refs++;
  return z;
}

void
unref_zone(zone *z) {
  z->refs--;
  if (!z->refs) free_zone(z);
}

int
main() {
  zone *last[COLS];
  zone *current[COLS];
  zone *best = new_zone(0, 0);
  int i, j;
  memset(last, 0, sizeof(last));

  for (j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
      unsigned int ele = eles[j][i];
      zone *z;
      /* printf("analyzing ele: %d at row %d, col: %d\n", ele, j, i); */
      if (i && (ele == eles[j][i-1])) {
        /* printf("  equal to left element\n"); */
        z = ref_zone(current[i-1]);
        if (j && (ele == eles[j-1][i])) {
          zone *z1 = last[i];
          /* printf("  equal to upper element\n"); */
          if (z != z1) {
            int k;
            /* printf("  collapsing zone %p\n", z1); */
            z->acu += z1->acu;
            for (k = 0; k < COLS; k++) {
              if (last[k] == z1) {
                last[k] = ref_zone(z);
                unref_zone(z1);
              }
            }
            for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
              if (current[k] == z1) {
                current[k] = ref_zone(z);
                unref_zone(z1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else if (j && (ele == eles[j-1][i])) {
        /* printf("  equal to upper element\n"); */
        z = ref_zone(last[i]);
      }
      else {
        /* printf("  new element\n"); */
        z = new_zone(j, i);
      }
      z->acu++;
      current[i] = z;
      /* printf("  element zone: %p\n", z); */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
      if (j) unref_zone(last[i]);
      last[i] = current[i];
      if (best->acu < current[i]->acu) {
        unref_zone(best);
        best = ref_zone(current[i]);
        /* printf("best zone changed to %p at row; %d, col: %d, acu: %d\n", best, best->row, best->col, best->acu); */
      }
    }
  }
  printf("best zone is at row: %d, col: %d, ele: %d, size: %d\n", best->row, best->col, eles[best->row][best->col], best->acu);
}
```

Comment: How does this help? Note that you still have to determine whether two `2` are adjacent or not. In the third row, you assign the letter `A` for the first `2` and the letter `F` for the second `2` in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your matrix is a graph, and the elements are vertices. Two vertices are connected if they are adjacent and have the same value. If you perform any search in that graph, be it [Breadth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Depth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), you'll get exactly what you want. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You could treat this like a picture in a paint application. Perform a [flood-fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) on each element in your 2D array (unless its filled already by something else) and keep track how many pixels you filled in each step.

If your array is declared like

```
int elements[5][5];
```

Then introduce a second array which tells whether you filled an element already (if you like, use a different type like `bool` if thats's okay in your C program):

```
int pixelFilled[5][5];
memset( pixelFilled, 0, sizeof( pixelFilled ) );
```

Next, write a recursive function which performs a flood fill and returns the numbers of elements which were filled (I'm writing this from the top of my head, no guarantee whatsoever that this function works as it is):

```
int floodFill( int x, int y ) {
  int filledPixels = 0;
  if ( !pixelFilled[x][y] ) {
    ++filledPixels;
    pixelFilled[x][y] = 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if ( x < 4 && elements[x+1][y] == elements[x][y] )
    filledPixels += floodFill( x + 1, y );
  if ( x > 0 && elements[x-1][y] == elements[x][y] )
    filledPixels += floodFill( x - 1, y );
  if ( y < 4  && elements[x][y+1] == elements[x][y] )
    filledPixels += floodFill( x, y + 1 );
  if ( y > 0  && elements[x][y-1] == elements[x][y] )
    filledPixels += floodFill( x, y - 1 );
  return filledPixels;
}
```

Finally, iterate over your array and try to fill it completely. Keep track of the largest filled array:

```
int thisArea = 0;
int largestArea = 0;
int x, y;
for ( y = 0; y < 5; ++y ) {
  for ( x = 0; x < 5; ++x ) {
    thisArea = floodFill( x, y );
    if (thisArea > largestArea ) {
      largestArea = thisArea;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, `largestArea` should contain the size of the longest chain of adjacent elements.

Comment: Hmmmmm... It seems you are going to flood fill also starting from "pixel" that have already been flood filled starting from a contiguous "pixel" of same value. Extremely inefficient.
BTW, for this kind of problems I usually remove the boundary checks (e.g. `x < 4`) by copying the input array in a bigger array with a frame of zeros, that will make the general condition `elements[x+1][y] == elements[x][y]` fail at the edge of the "image".

Comment: You probably just miss an `else return 0` at the beginning of the `floodFill` function. In fact without that you enter an infinite recursion :-)

Comment: @Antonio Indeed, coming back to this answer after almost nine years (and six years after your comment), I see that I should have added an early `return` to avoid recursing unnecessarily. The optimization is simple enough and should yield good improvements for larger arrays. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

1. define another 2d array of the same size, initialize all cells to 0
2. set maxval to 0
3. if helper array is full of 1's go to 5, otherwise find a cell with 0 and do:
   3.1 change value of the cell to 1
   3.2 set a counter to 1
   3.3 check all adjacent cells, if they're 0 in the helper array and the same value as current cell in the input array then counter++ and go to 2.1 with new coordinates.
4. maxval = max(maxval,counter), go to 3
5. return maxval

steps 3.1-3.3 should be implemented as a recursive function which takes coordinate and both arrays as arguments and returns 1+the sum of the returned values from the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

I love this kind of problems :-) so here it is my answer.
As said by Frerich Raabe, this can be solved with a floodFill function. For example, `opencv` library would provide such a function off the shelf.

Please forgive me if in the following code you'll find traces of C++, in case they should be simple to be replaced.

```
typedef struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
} Point;

int areaOfBiggestContiguousRegion(int* mat,int nRows, int nCols) {
  int maxArea = 0;
  int currValue, queueSize, queueIndex;  
  int* aux;
  Point queue[1000]; //Stores the points I need to label
  Point newPoint, currentPoint;
  int x,y,x2,y2;
  //Code: allocate support array aux of same size of mat
  //Code: fill aux of zeros

  for (y = 0; y < nRows; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < nCols; x++)
      if (aux[y * nCols + x] == 0) {//I find a pixel not yet labeled, my seed for the next flood fill
        queueIndex = 0; //Contains the index to the next element in the queue
        queueSize = 0;

        currValue = mat[y * nCols + x]; //The "color" of the current spot
        aux[y * nCols + x] = 1;
        newPoint.x = x;
        newPoint.y = y;
        queue[queueSize] = newPoint;
        queueSize++; 

        while(queueIndex != queueSize) {
          currPoint = queue[queueIndex];
          queueIndex++;

          //Look left, right, up, down

          x2 = currPoint.x - 1;
          y2 = currPoint.y;
          //Some copy & paste, sorry I have been too long on C++ to remember correctly about C functions
          if (x2 >= 0 && aux[y2 * nCols + x2] == 0 && mat[y2 * nCols + x2] == currValue) {
            aux[y2 * nCols + x2] = 1;
            newPoint.x = x2;
            newPoint.y = y2;
            queue[queueSize] = newPoint;
            queueSize++; 
          }

          x2 = currPoint.x + 1;
          y2 = currPoint.y;
          //Some copy & paste, sorry I have been too long on C++ to remember correctly about C functions
          if (x2 < nCols && aux[y2 * nCols + x2] == 0 && mat[y2 * nCols + x2] == currValue) {
            aux[y2 * nCols + x2] = 1;
            newPoint.x = x2;
            newPoint.y = y2;
            queue[queueSize] = newPoint;
            queueSize++; 
          }

          x2 = currPoint.x;
          y2 = currPoint.y - 1;
          //Some copy & paste, sorry I have been too long on C++ to remember correctly about C functions
          if (y2 >= 0 && aux[y2 * nCols + x2] == 0 && mat[y2 * nCols + x2] == currValue) {
            aux[y2 * nCols + x2] = 1;
            newPoint.x = x2;
            newPoint.y = y2;
            queue[queueSize] = newPoint;
            queueSize++; 
          }

          x2 = currPoint.x;
          y2 = currPoint.y + 1;
          //Some copy & paste, sorry I have been too long on C++ to remember correctly about C functions
          if (y2 < nRows && aux[y2 * nCols + x2] == 0 && mat[y2 * nCols + x2] == currValue) {
            aux[y2 * nCols + x2] = 1;
            newPoint.x = x2;
            newPoint.y = y2;
            queue[queueSize] = newPoint;
            queueSize++; 
          }
        } //while

      if (queueSize > maxArea)
        maxArea = queueSize; //If necessary we could store other details like currentValue
      }//if (aux...

return maxArea;
}
```

Note: In C++ using std containers and a constructor for `Point` it becomes much more compact