# How to get longest line of 1's in array/matrix

Tags: c, arrays

My task is to find "longest line" of 1's in array. Hoizontal and Vertical.
Array is made only of 0's and 1's, and looks for example like this:

```
4 4
0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 1 0
```

Output should print [ i ][ j ] of "starting" 1, and [ i ][ j ] of "ending" 1., So horizontal should be [1][0] [3][0].

I am using my getcolor() function to get value on [ i ][ j ] spot.

I am thinking about this for WAAAAY to long, spent almost whole week on this.I had some ideas, but none worked. Maybe because I am new to C and completely new to arrays.

I know that I should go through the array, on every 1 found it should save the coordinates to "start", and go to next, saving every 1 found to "end". After 0 is found, compare the lenght, and if the lenght is largest, overwrite the lenght. But I didn't manage to write the code right. Can someone help me ad write the code? Thank you very much.

Edit: This is what I have, but I am just at the start and it doesn't work already:

```
if(arr != NULL) {
  while (j < arr->cols) {
    while (i <=arr->rows) {
            if (getcolor(arr, i, j) == 1) {
                startI = i;
                startJ = j;
                break;
            }
            else
            i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while (i <=arr->rows) {
            if (getcolor(arr, i, j) == 1) {
                endI = i;
                endJ = j;
            }
            i++;
    }
    i=0;

   printf("start %d %d\nend %d %d\nline %d\n\n", startI, startJ, endI, endJ, line);
   j++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show some pieces of the code you have written already.

Comment: You've got the general idea laid out in your description, please post the code you tried and tell us why it didn't work.

Comment: This is similar to finding subarray with max sum.

Comment: @0xF1 Subarray makes sense for row's but not columns. Unless I'm misunderstanding the meaning of subarray?

Comment: @nonsensickle : You can consider all columns as multiple 1-D arrays.

Comment: you should actually start counting from the first time a `1` appears and stop the count on that subset for the first `0` that appears. Even if you find `0` you need to keep counting for another potential subset, for example the 3rd column ( from left to right ) in your matrix still got 2 more `1` after the `0` and if you just stop after the first `0` you get the wrong reading about this.

Comment: @0xF1 Ah, so you weren't talking about the memory layout of C arrays but generic multiple array's that a matrix consists of. Ok, that makes sense now. I was coming from the angle that each row is an array and all rows are sequentially arranged in memory. Meaning that your columns are spread out through those subarrays... But since all column elements are at equal spacings from one another I wasn't sure if that could constitute a "subarray".

Comment: @DaveSwersky Posted it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397439/finding-all-adjacent-elements-in-a-2d-array-in-c your question is almost a duplicate of this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being too late. I didn't write it exactly how you want it, but this will realy help you. Just read it and you will get the idea.

Link to code http://pastebin.com/vLATASab

Or view it here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int arr[4][4];
    arr[0][0] = 0;arr[0][1] = 1;arr[0][2] = 1;arr[0][3] = 1;
    arr[1][0] = 0;arr[1][1] = 1;arr[1][2] = 0;arr[1][3] = 1;
    arr[2][0] = 0;arr[2][1] = 1;arr[2][2] = 1;arr[2][3] = 0;
    arr[3][0] = 1;arr[3][1] = 0;arr[3][2] = 1;arr[3][3] = 1;

    int i, j, k;
    int line, line_start, line_end, line_max = 0;
    int col, col_start, col_end, col_max = 0;

    // Horizently
    for (k=0; k<4; k++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if (!arr[k][i]) continue;
            for (j=i; j<4; j++)
            {
                if (!arr[k][j]) break;
            }
            j--;
            if (j-i+1>line_max)
            {
                line = k;
                line_start = i;
                line_end = j;
                line_max = line_end-line_start+1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("horizontaly\n");
    printf("start: [%d][%d]\n", line, line_start);
    printf("end: [%d][%d]\n", line, line_end);

    // Verticaly
    for (k=0; k<4; k++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if (!arr[i][k]) continue;
            for (j=i; j<4; j++)
            {
                if (!arr[j][k]) break;
            }
            j--;
            if (j-i+1>col_max)
            {
                col = k;
                col_start = i;
                col_end = j;
                col_max = col_end-col_start+1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nverticaly\n");
    printf("start: [%d][%d]\n", col_start, col);
    printf("end: [%d][%d]\n", col_end, col);

}
```

Comment: It will be more efficient if you replace your `for (j=i; j<4; j++)` with `for (;i<4;i++)` (probably more readable implemented using a `while`). (You'll need to store in a temp variable the value of `i` where the current sequence started). The problem I am addressing is that if in a row you have 0111111111 your implementation finds 9 sequences of one, the first of length 9, the second of length 8, etc... And, of course, you shouldn't write `4` but some variable or constant `nCols` and `NRows`

Comment: @rullof Thank you soo much. And do you have idea how to find largest square of 1's with using those lines?

Comment: @user3021851 Update your question, or ask a new one so people can help.

Answer (score 3):

When you're stuck on a problem like this, it helps to break it down into smaller problems that are easier to solve. Your problem is a perfect example. It looks like you're trying to solve the whole problem at once, and as you've seen it gets a little hairy with the nested loops and all. So, how can you make the problem simpler? Well, it'd be simpler if you could just snap your fingers and find the longest line on a single row. Likewise, it'd be nice to have an easy way to get the longest line in a single column. So, consider writing functions like these:

```
int longestLineInRow(int board[][], int width, int height, int &start, int &end)
{
    // returns length, with start and end being the indices of the beginning and end of the line
}

int longestLineInColumn(int board[][], int width, int height, int &start, int &end)
{
    // returns length, with start and end being the indices of the beginning and end of the line
}
```

Now it's easy to find the row with the longest line: you just find the longest line in each row, and pick the row that returns the greatest value. Same for columns.

I haven't solved the problem of finding the longest line within a row or column for you, but that's a simpler task that you can probably solve yourself once you stop trying to solve the whole problem at once.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the function you are showing does only half of the problem, that is finding the longest vertical sequence of 1s. You'll have to write a mirrored function to find the longest horizontal sequence.

I will tell you the mistakes I see in your approach:

- You do not compute anywhere the length of the found sequence
- You do not store the length and the indexes of the longest sequence
- `while (i <=arr->rows)` should be `while (i < arr->rows)`, otherwise you'll also look in row number 4, when you have only row 0, 1, 2 and 3.
- You reset `i` after having found the beginning of sequence of 1s. `i` instead should keep advancing
- You save also `j` in `startJ`, but `j` is not going to change, as long you are examining the same column
- You look for only one sequence of 1s per column
- "horizontally" and "vertically" should be spelled with two "L" :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct field {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int *field;
} Field;

Field init_Field(){//Mock
    Field f;
    int data[4][4] = {
        {0, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 0}
    };
    f.rows = 4;
    f.cols = 4;
    int size = f.rows * f.cols;
    f.field = malloc(size * sizeof(*(f.field)));
    memcpy(f.field, data, size*sizeof(*(f.field)));
    return f;
}

int getcolor(Field *f, int r, int c){
    if(r < 0 || r >= f->rows) return -1;
    if(c < 0 || c >= f->cols) return -1;
    return f->field[ r * f->cols + c];
}

int search(Field *f, int r, int c, int dr, int dc, int level, int maxLen, int nowMax){
    //dr,dc : incremental
    if(dr > 0 && f->rows - r + level <= nowMax) return -1;//stop search
    if(dc > 0 && f->cols - c + level <= nowMax) return -1;//stop search
    if(level == maxLen)
        return level;
    if(getcolor(f, r, c)==1)
        return search(f, r + dr, c + dc, dr, dc, level + 1, maxLen, nowMax);

    return level;
}

int main(){
    Field f = init_Field();
    int HMaxLen = 0, HMaxRow, HMaxCol;
    int RMaxLen = 0, RMaxRow, RMaxCol;
    int r, c, len;
    for(r = 0; r < f.rows;++r){
        for(c = 0; c < f.cols;++c){
            len = search(&f, r, c, 0, 1, 0, f.cols, HMaxLen);
            if(len > HMaxLen){
                HMaxLen = len;
                HMaxRow = r;
                HMaxCol = c;
            }
            len = search(&f, r, c, 1, 0, 0, f.rows, RMaxLen);
            if(len > RMaxLen){
                RMaxLen = len;
                RMaxRow = r;
                RMaxCol = c;
            }
        }
    }
    free(f.field);
    printf("start %d %d\n  end %d %d\n\n", HMaxRow, HMaxCol, HMaxRow, HMaxCol + HMaxLen-1);
    printf("start %d %d\n  end %d %d\n\n", RMaxRow, RMaxCol, RMaxRow + RMaxLen-1, RMaxRow);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
void Reset(int s[2], int e[2], int cs[2],  int ce[2], int *resetState, int cc, int pc)
{
*resetState=0;
            if(cc>pc)
            {
                s[0]=cs[0];
                s[1]=cs[1];
                e[0]=ce[0];
                e[1]=ce[1];
            }
}
void Decide(int value, int s[2], int e[2], int cs[2],  int ce[2], int *resetState, int *cc, int *pc, int i, int j)
{
if(value==0&&*resetState)
{
        Reset(s, e, cs, ce, resetState, *cc, *pc);  
}
else if(value)
{
            if(*resetState==0)
            {
                cs[0]=i;
                cs[1]=j;
                if(*cc>*pc)
                {
                    *pc=*cc;
                }
                *cc=0;
                *resetState=1;
            }
            ce[0]=i;
            ce[1]=j;
            ++*cc;
}
}

void FindLargestRowNdColumn(int a[20][20],int row, int col, int hs[2], int  he[2], int vs[2], int ve[2])
{
int i, j, rcc=0, rpc=0, ccc=0, cpc=0;
int chs[2]={0,0}, che[2]={0,0}, cvs[2]={0,0}, cve[2]={0, 0};
int resetRow=0, restCol=0;
for(i=0; i<row; ++i)
{
    for(j=0; j<col; ++j)
    {
        Decide(a[i][j], hs, he, chs, che, &resetRow, &rcc, &rpc, i, j);
        Decide(a[j][i], vs, ve, cvs, cve, &restCol, &ccc, &cpc, i, j);
    }
    Reset(hs, he, chs, che, &resetRow, rcc, rpc);   
    Reset(vs, ve, cvs, cve, &restCol, ccc, cpc);    
}
}

void main()
{
int a[20][20], indexRow, colIndex;
int colum, row,hs[2], he[2], vs[2], ve[2];
printf("Enter number of rows and columns\n");
scanf("%d%d", &row, &colum);
printf("Enter the array\n");
for(indexRow=0; indexRow<row; ++indexRow)
{
    for(colIndex=0; colIndex<colum; ++colIndex)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[indexRow][colIndex]);
    }
}
FindLargestRowNdColumn(a, row, colum, hs, he, vs, ve);
printf("Row [%d][%d] [%d][%d]\n", hs[0], hs[1], he[0], he[1]);
printf("column [%d][%d] [%d][%d]\n", vs[0], vs[1], ve[0], ve[1]);
}
```