# How to recognize a square in a bitmap?

Tags: algorithm

I came across this interview question:

- In a N x N bi-dimensional array of boolean elements, how do you determine if the values form a square?

For example:

```
true true true true
true false false true 
true false false true 
true true true true
```

form a square.

I figured that I have to start by checking if there is a square in the middle (if N is odd that is always true) and then recursively checking the values at the perimeter.

- Is this the best way to do it or is there a better, faster, way to find out?

Comment: personally i would iterate over the array and print out 0 for false and 1 for true. then look at the result and see if it's a square...

Comment: Will the square always be orthogonally oriented (i.e., not rotated)?  Then it's relatively easy.  However, if the square could be rotated, and possibly not even pixel-aligned, then it's pretty hard.  A lot more interesting though.

Comment: it never occurred to me that it could be rotated, the interviewer didn't say but I'm sure he was expecting to hear that question. Is there a general approach for rotated, pixel-aligned cases?

Comment: It's not clear what "to form a square" means, not even with your example. Are you looking for outlines of squares that are made up of `true` values, that enclose at least one `false` and that can be anywhere in the bitmap? Or are you just checking, that the whole (square) bitmap is `false` and the borders of the bitmap are `true`? (I suppose that the squares are aligned to the bitmap borders and not rotated.)

Comment: Is the question to find if there's just a square and nothing else? Or a square somewhere in the grid? Or a square anywhere in the grid, which may contain noise? Is a single pixel a square?

Comment: [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) seems to be the most general method, applicable to rotated squares

Comment: It's an interview question. I doubt that we have to deal with detecting rotated squares in a bitmap image. (The question is a bit fuzzy, though.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding square made of 1's in a 2D array/matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554827/finding-square-made-of-1s-in-a-2d-array-matrix)

Comment: Is this a square - `[[true,true],[true,true]]` ?

Answer (score 2):

A squre could be determined by two points. Let's say the left-top point `(x1,y1)` and the right-bottom point `(x2,y2)`. And, let's use `1` as `true`, and `0` as `false`.

Consider an array:

```py
array = [None] * 5
array[0] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
array[1] = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
array[2] = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
array[3] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
array[4] = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

It's obviously that `(0,0)(3,3)` forms a square in this case. And we could find a property that:

**A square is formed if and only if:**

- **By adding the two row borders together, you will get a sequence of `2`;
   The length of the sequence is equal to the distance between to two row borders.**
- **By adding the two column borders together, you will get a sequence of `2`;
  The length of the sequence is equal to the distance between to two column borders.**

---

Exploiting the property above, you would get an [image: O(n^3)] algorithm:

```py
row_segment = []
col_segment = []
for v1 in range(len(array)):
    for v2 in range(v1+1, len(array)):
        add_row = [array[v1][col]+array[v2][col] for col in range(len(array))]
        add_col = [array[row][v1]+array[row][v2] for row in range(len(array))]
        row_distance = v2-v1
        row_sum = sum(add_row[:row_distance+1])
        col_sum = sum(add_col[:row_distance+1])
        for i in range(len(array)-row_distance):
            j = i+row_distance
            if row_sum == 2*(row_distance+1):
                row_segment.append([v1, i, v2, j])
            if col_sum == 2*(row_distance+1):
                col_segment.append([i, v1, j, v2])
            row_sum = row_sum - add_row[i] + add_row[j+1] if j+1 < len(array) else None
            col_sum = col_sum - add_col[i] + add_col[j+1] if j+1 < len(array) else None

for i in row_segment:
    if i in col_segment:
        print "Square ({x1}, {y1}) ({x2}, {y2})".format(x1=i[0], y1=i[1], x2=i[2], y2=i[3])
```

---

Let's run some tests:

Test 1:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0

Square (1, 2) (3, 4)
```

Test 2:

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1

Square (1, 0) (3, 2)
```

Test 3:

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0

Square (1, 0) (3, 2)
Square (1, 2) (3, 4)
```

Test 4:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1   

No squares found
```

Comment: How is it obvious that (0, 0) to (4, 3) forms a square? It's the outline of a rectangle, sure, but it's a square only if `x2 - x1 == y2 - y1`.

Comment: Oh! I was trying to find all the rectangles. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @MOehm Done. Please review again.

Comment: Well, you've tested your code already and provided a test case that includes a non-square rectangle, so there's no need to get a stamp of approval from me. I had just pointed out a trivial error in your first solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer and comments.  my original question was oriented to find a full figure (not the perimeter of a square with a hollow interior)