# How can I find line of the same elements in a 2D matrix?

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, matrix

I have custom size matrix and should find line of with specified length. I need coordinates of first and last elements in this line.
For example:
Line length is 3.
My matrix is

- 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
- 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
- 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
- 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

So my answer is [0, 3], [2, 3].

If line length is 4.
My matrix is

- 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
- 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
- 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
- 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

My answer is [0, 4], [3, 1].

Elements can has any type (number, char, string, objects, etc.).
It does not matter what programming language I use, because I just want to understand algorithm.
Sorry for my bad English. Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  what do [x,y] represent?

Comment: I think he is asking how to find "lines" of '1's (either horizontal, vertical or diagonal) within the matrix. x and y would then be the coordinates of the start and end of those "lines".

Comment: http://yadi.sk/d/S6yoSCXiKahhy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20528602/971127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the exact solution to your question, but it should be close enough for you to be able to transfer it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define WIDTH   8
#define HEIGHT  8

bool matrix[HEIGHT][WIDTH] =
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
};

struct position
{
    int row;
    int column;
};

enum direction { south, east, southwest, southeast };
char *dir_s[] = { "south", "east", "southwest", "southeast" };


int search(bool m[WIDTH][HEIGHT], struct position start, enum direction dir)
{
    switch (dir)
    {
        case east:
            if ((++start.column < WIDTH) && m[start.row][start.column])
            {
                return 1 + search(m, start, east);
            }
            break;

        case south:
            if ((++start.row < HEIGHT) && m[start.row][start.column])
            {
                return 1 + search(m, start, south);
            }
            break;

        case southwest:    
            if ((++start.row < HEIGHT) && (--start.column >= 0) && m[start.row][start.column])
            {
                return 1 + search(m, start, southwest);
            }
            break;

        case southeast:
            if ((++start.row < HEIGHT) && (++start.column < WIDTH) && m[start.row][start.column])
            {
                return 1 + search(m, start, southeast);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct position maxpos;
    enum direction maxdir;
    int length;
    int maxlength = 0;

    for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++)
        for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++)
            if (matrix[row][column])
            {
                struct position pos = { row, column };
                enum direction dir;

                for (dir = south; dir <= southeast; dir++)
                {
                    length =  1 + search(matrix, pos, dir);
                    if (length > maxlength)
                    {
                        maxlength = length;
                        maxdir = dir;
                        maxpos = pos;
                    }
                }
            }
    printf("found max length %d on (%d,%d) in direction %s\n", maxlength, maxpos.row, maxpos.column, dir_s[maxdir]);
}
```

Note that search calls itself recursively, so you'd better not use this for very large datasets.